# Javascript Loop over elements and click a link using WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, q, webdriver-io

I am using Javascript, webdriverio (v2.1.2) to perform some data extraction from an internal site. So the idea is

- Authenticate
- Open the required URL, when authenticated
- In the new page, search for an anchor tag having specific keyword
- Once found, click on the anchor tag

Below is what I have tried and it works (last two points). I had to use Q and async to achieve it. I was hoping to use only Q to achieve it. **Can someone help me, on how to achieve it using Q only ??**

```
    var EmployeeAllocationDetails = (function () {
'use stricy';
/*jslint nomen: true */
var Q = require('Q'),
    async = require('async'),   
    _ead_name = 'Employee Allocation Details',
    goToEadFromHome;

goToEadFromHome = function (browserClient) {
    browserClient.pause(500);
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    browserClient.elements('table.rmg td.workListTD div.tab2 div.contentDiv>a', function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(new Error('Unable to get EAD page. ' + JSON.stringify(err)));
        } else {

        async.each(results.value, function (oneResult, callback) {
                console.log('Processing: ' + JSON.stringify(oneResult));
                browserClient.elementIdText(oneResult.ELEMENT, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        if (err.message.indexOf('referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM') > -1 ){
                            callback();
                        } else {
                            callback('Error while processing :' + JSON.stringify(oneResult) + '. ' + err);
                        }
                    } else if(!result){
                        console.log('result undefined. Cannot process: ' + JSON.stringify(oneResult));
                        callback();
                    } else if(result.value.trim() === _ead_name){
                        deferred.resolve(oneResult);
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }, function (err) {
                // if any of the processing produced an error, err would equal that error
            if( err ) {
        // One of the iterations produced an error.
        // All processing will now stop.
            console.log('A processing failed to process. ' + err);
            } else {
            console.log('All results have been processed successfully');
            }
            }); //end of async.each

        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

return {
    launchEad : goToEadFromHome
  }
})();
module.exports = EmployeeAllocationDetails;
```

Related Github Issue link https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/123

Comment: Seems to me you are using the correct and recommended method. Async and Q are used for different things - while Q is used for promise interface, Async is used for flow control. There are ways to write it without async, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `async`. I think your code is great. It runs everything in parallel and it handles error well.

If

If you want to remove `async`, there are several options:

- use Q flow control
- copy paste async's implementation
- implement it yourself

If you try to use Q's flow control it will look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
   var getTextActions = [];
   function createAction(element){ 
        return function(){
             return element.getText();
        }
   }

   each(elements, function(element){ getTextActions.push( createAction(element) ) }); 
   Q.all(getTextActions).then(function(results) {
      ... iterate all results and resolve promise with first matching element.. 
   } );
```

note this implementation has worse performance. It will first get the text from all elements, and only then try to resolve your promise. You implementation is better as it all runs in parallel.

I don't recommend implementing it yourself, but if you still want to, it will look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var elementsCount = elements.length; 
elements.each(function(element){
   element.getText(function(err, result){
      elementsCount --;
      if ( !!err ) { logger.error(err); /** async handles this much better **/  } 
      if ( isThisTheElement(result) ) { deferred.resolve(result); }
      if ( elementsCount == 0 ){ // in case we ran through all elements and didn't find any
            deferred.resolve(null); // since deferred is resolved only once, calling this again if we found the item will have no effect
      }
   })
})
```

if something is unclear, or if I didn't hit the spot, let me know and I will improve the answer.